# Render 1 image in 3 repeated components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, components

I'm relatively new to React JS and have encountered my first blocker.

I have a component that renders 3 pieces of information and each piece requires a different image that goes with it. See this image: [image: too many images]

This is obviously each image, rendered 3 times instead of once.
It should look something like this: [image: correct approach]

The only issue is, there are 3 images and I'm not sure how to reflect each other image on each respective component if that makes sense. I've tried a couple approaches but either end up with 1 image or all 3. It makes sense as I render that component 3 times so I understand my error, but what is the best solution in this situation?

My current approach:

```
const images = [
    {
        id: "img1",
        source: require("../../assets/images/image-retro-pcs.jpg")
    },
    // {
    //     id: "img2",
    //     source: require("../../assets/images/image-top-laptops.jpg")
    // },
    // {
    //     id: "img3",
    //     source: require("../../assets/images/image-gaming-growth.jpg")
    // }
];

const FooterItem = (props) => {
    const imageSource = images.map((image) => 
        <img 
            src={image.source} 
            alt="" 
            className={classes.image} 
            key={image.id}
        />)

    return (
        <div className={classes.itemContainer}>
            {imageSource}
            <div className={classes.footerItems}>
                <h2 className={classes.h2}>{props.number}</h2>
                <h3 className={classes.h3}>{props.title}</h3>
                <p className={classes.p}>{props.info}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FooterItem;
```

So with those 2 commented out, we get 1 image in each correct component.

The other component code is:

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.footer}>
        <FooterItem 
            number="01"
            title="Reviving Retro PCs"
            info="What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?"
        />
        <FooterItem 
            number="02"
            title="Top 10 Laptops of 2022"
            info="Our best picks for various needs and budgets."
        />
        <FooterItem 
            number="03"
            title="The Growth of Gaming"
            info="How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities."
        />
    </div>
  );
};
```

What would be the best 3 to not have 3 images rendered but instead 1? a forEach loop?

Edit:
I resolved it by refactoring my code like this:

```
const images = [
    {
        id: "img1",
        source: require("../../assets/images/image-retro-pcs.jpg"),
        number:"01",
        title:"Reviving Retro PCs",
        info:"What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?"
    },
    {
        id: "img2",
        source: require("../../assets/images/image-top-laptops.jpg"),
        number:"02",
        title:"Top 10 Laptops of 2022",
        info:"Our best picks for various needs and budgets."
    },
    {
        id: "img3",
        source: require("../../assets/images/image-gaming-growth.jpg"),
        number:"03",
        title:"The Growth of Gaming",
        info:"How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities."
    }
];

const FooterItem = () => {
    const imageSource = images.map((image) => 
    <div className={classes.itemContainer} key={image.id}>
        <img 
            src={image.source} 
            alt="" 
            className={classes.image} 
        />
        <div className={classes.footerItems}>
                <h2 className={classes.h2}>{image.number}</h2>
                <h3 className={classes.h3}>{image.title}</h3>
                <p className={classes.p}>{image.info}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )

    return (
        <div className={classes.itemContainer}>
            {imageSource}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FooterItem;

OTHER FILE:
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.footer}>
        <FooterItem />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You would use `map` to produce an array of `FooterItem` components. See the [React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists) for some good info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send one more prop that will contain id of image as:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-black-cnr9eq?file=/src/App.js)

```
<FooterItem
        number="01"
        title="Reviving Retro PCs"
        info="What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?"
        imageId="img1"
      />
```

and inside the `FooterItem`, you can [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) image using `imageID` as:

```
const image = images.find((o) => o.id === props.imageId);
```

and render it as:

```
<div className={classes.itemContainer}>
      {image ? (
        <img
          src={image.source}
          alt=""
          className={classes.image}
          key={image.id}
        />
      ) : null}
      <div className={classes.footerItems}>
        <h2 className={classes.h2}>{props.number}</h2>
        <h3 className={classes.h3}>{props.title}</h3>
        <p className={classes.p}>{props.info}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

To improve your code more then you can create an array of objects that contain all footer data and then render it as:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-haze-i8sdki?file=/src/App.js)

```
const Footer = () => {
  const footerData = [
    {
      number: "01",
      title: "Reviving Retro PCs",
      info: "What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?",
      imageId: "img1"
    },
    {
      number: "02",
      title: "Top 10 Laptops of 2022",
      info: "Our best picks for various needs and budgets.",
      imageId: "img2"
    },
    {
      number: "03",
      title: "The Growth of Gaming",
      info: "How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities.",
      imageId: "img3"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className={classes.footer}>
      {footerData.map((o) => {
        return (
          <FooterItem
            key={o.number}
            number={o.number}
            title={o.title}
            info={o.info}
            imageId={o.imageId}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I actually managed to resolve it myself before seeing your solution, but thank you very much for your solution. It's giving me a lot to think of. I refactored my code like this (see edit), do you think this is also a good approach?

Comment: @Chaffe even cleaner.